# Vertical scroll bar appears only when I push resize corner in the dialog jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

I have a dialog with max-height=400px and the problem when the content height is more than 400px the vertical scroll bar doesn't appear, but when I push the resize corner of the dialog and close it, then re-open it the vertical scroll bar appears and works fine. Any suggestions or thoughts how to solve this issue? here is the ui-dialog and ui-dialog-content:

```
.ui-dialog {
    max-height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0.2em;
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
}

.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-content {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border: 0 none;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    position: relative;
}
```

Here is the peice of code where I use this dialog:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function formatViewLink(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
       return "<a onClick='openDialog("+cellvalue+")'>" + '<img src="images/view_detail.png" />' + "</a>";  
      } 

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function openDialog(isobolId) {
                $("#selected_structs").load("${viewUrl}?isobolId="+isobolId);
                $("#selected_structs").dialog('open');
        }
</script>
<@sj.dialog 
        id="selected_structs" 
        title="Version Structures" 
        autoOpen="false" 
        modal="true"
        width="400"
        height="auto"
        position="['center','top']"
>
</@sj.dialog>
```

Comment: could you please provide fiddle link or some code from your app. this may help us to understand your problem clearly.

Comment: you can use .ui-dialog { overflow:auto;} in your code. it may clear your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by changing the `jquery-ui.css` file inside the `struts2jquery-plugin-3.3.1.jar`. in line **435** the `overfolw:hidden` to `overflow:auto`. then I empty the browser's cache and it work like charm :-).